# Laravel 10 How to change SMTP details on the fly without changing config values

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, swiftmailer, laravel-10

I'm trying to change SMTP details on the fly for web or queue also.

I have tried this link : https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel, but this example not working in Laravel 10.

Not only that, but I also try this code :

```
$configuration = $this->configuration();
$customer = Customer::find(1);
$notification['message'] = "Message";

$mailer = new CustomerMail($customer, $notification['message'], $configuration['smtp_from_email'], $configuration['smtp_from_name']);
$mailer->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($configuration) {
    $message->getHeaders()
        ->addTextHeader('X-SMTP-Transport', $configuration['smtp_transpot'])
        ->addTextHeader('X-SMTP-Host', $configuration['smtp_host'])
        ->addTextHeader('X-SMTP-Port', $configuration['smtp_port'])
        ->addTextHeader('X-SMTP-Encryption', $configuration['smtp_encryption'])
        ->addTextHeader('X-SMTP-Username', $configuration['smtp_username'])
        ->addTextHeader('X-SMTP-Password', $configuration['smtp_password']);
 });
 Mail::to($customer->{Customer::EMAIL})->send($mailer);
```

This code also not working for me, How can I change SMTP details on the fly in Laravel 10 without effecting config values.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed some logic as mention @kawax "Laravel10 using Symfony Mailer instead of SwiftMailer", so checked Laravel core files and found "Illuminate\Mail\MailManager" class handle configuration of Symfony Transport with "createSymfonyTransport()" function.

I am still using Laravel News blog : https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel, but Change some logic in AppServiceProvider class for Laravel 10.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;
    use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
    use Illuminate\Mail\MailManager;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         */
        public function register(): void
        {
            /* Set custom mailer to send mail tennat SMTP detail */
            $this->app->bind('user.mailer', function ($app, $parameters) {
                if ($parameters['smtp_transpot'] == 'smtp') {
                    // $from_email = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_from_email');
                    // $from_name = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_from_name');
                    $configSmtp = [
                        "transport" => $parameters['smtp_transpot'],
                        "host" => Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_host'),
                        "port" => Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_port'),
                        "encryption" => Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_encryption'),
                        "username" => Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_username'),
                        "password" => Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_password'),
                        "timeout" => null,
                        "local_domain" => null
                    ];
                    $mailManager = new MailManager($app);
                    $smtpTransportFactory = $mailManager->createSymfonyTransport($configSmtp);

                    $mailer = new Mailer('smtp', $app->get('view'), $smtpTransportFactory, $app->get('events'));
                    // $mailer->alwaysFrom($from_email, $from_name);
                    // $mailer->alwaysReplyTo($from_email, $from_name);

                    return $mailer;
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         */
        public function boot(): void
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Send mail in controller (same as queue)

```
$configuration = $this->configuration();
$customer = Customer::find(1);
$notification['message'] = "Message";
$customerMailer = new CustomerMail($customer, $notification['message'], $configuration['smtp_from_email'], $configuration['smtp_from_name']);
// call here
$mailer = app()->makeWith('user.mailer', $configuration);
$mailer->to($customer->{Customer::EMAIL})->send($customerMailer);
```

This work for me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel10 using Symfony Mailer instead of SwiftMailer.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer

config overrides are temporary and are not saved.

```php
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.username' => '']);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.password' => '']);

// sendmail
```

This only takes effect during the current request.

Comment: Thank you, @kawax Actually I have tried this, but it's not working while sending email via queue.